# Woocommerce add image after add to cart button

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

It seems weird,  but am trying to add a background image after an element(button) but for some reason, the image does not show.

```css
    .single_add_to_cart_button:after {
        content: '';
        width: 50px;
        height: 9px;
        display: inline-block;
        background: url(/images/arrow.png);
        background-position: 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed">Place order</button>
```

For some reason, the image does not show and I even tried using a live URL

Note: If I try using a paragraph it works as you can see in my pen [here](https://codepen.io/melodiacapoeira/pen/byjEQq)

How can I add an image from the template directory after my add to cart button?

In a simpler solution, I tried using a hook but I am also struggling to access the image using bloginfo:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
    echo '<img src="<?php bloginfo("template_directory")/images/logo/logo.png">';   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error as you are using `<?php` in a echo statement as well as `bloginfo($option)` echos out a value so request you to use `get_template_directory_uri()` to get the path to the template directory which will returns a string

your code will look like below snippet:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart_button_func' );

function add_content_after_addtocart_button_func() {
    echo '<img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo/logo.png">';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works just fine here (I added some additional styling)

```css
.single_add_to_cart_button {
  background-color: #ededed;
  border: none;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.single_add_to_cart_button:after {
  content: '';
  width: 4rem;
  height: 2rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(http://www.gentleface.com/i/free_toolbar_icons_16x16_black.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt disabled wc-variation-selection-needed">Place order</button>
```